# convert matrix to image

Tags: python, image, matrix

How would I go about going converting a list of lists of ints into a matrix plot in Python?

The example data set is:

```
[[3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 0, 5, 0, 3, 2],
 [5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3, 5, 0, 0],
 [2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3],
 [4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 0, 4, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 1, 0, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1],
 [4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 0],
 [2, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 0, 5, 4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1],
 [3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1]]
```

To give you an idea of what I'm looking for, the function MatrixPlot in Mathematica gives me this image for this data set:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may try

```
from pylab import *
A = rand(5,5)
figure(1)
imshow(A, interpolation='nearest')
grid(True)
```

[image]

[source](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html)

Comment: exactly what does interpolation="nearest" do? I'm having trouble finding documentation on its functionality

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps [matshow()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/matshow.html) from matplotlib is what you need.

Comment: Also pcolor: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pyplot from matplotlib, follows the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.imshow(
[[3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 0, 5, 0, 3, 2],
 [5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3, 5, 0, 0],
 [2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3],
 [4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 0, 4, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 1, 0, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1],
 [4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 5, 4, 2, 0],
 [2, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 0, 5, 4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1],
 [3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1]], interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

The output would be:

[image: Plot of the matrix]