# Create symmetric matrix from pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I'd like to create a plot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4841611/1778537).

In my case, I need a symmetric `20x20` matrix where the entry `(i,j)` should be taken from the `ns` column within data file which has the format (just a piece):

```
areas ns i j
0.500000 1.00 10 10
0.513611 0.80 10 11
0.582778 0.12 10 12
0.725278 0.00 10 13
0.528472 0.59 10 14
0.655000 0.00 10 15
0.616667 0.03 10 16
0.751806 0.00 10 17
0.519722 0.71 10 18
0.917045 0.00 10 19
0.849583 0.00 10 20
0.804333 0.00 1 10
0.500000 1.00 11 11
0.599861 0.06 11 12
0.611389 0.03 11 13
0.525417 0.64 11 14
0.533889 0.52 11 15
0.590833 0.09 11 16
0.609722 0.04 11 17
0.573472 0.17 11 18
0.802652 0.00 11 19
0.764000 0.00 1 11
0.677083 0.00 11 20
0.730667 0.00 1 12
0.879667 0.00 1 13
0.778667 0.00 1 14
0.858333 0.00 1 15
0.726333 0.00 1 16
0.884000 0.00 1 17
0.772667 0.00 1 18
0.959545 0.00 1 19
0.500000 1.00 1 1
0.919667 0.00 1 20
0.500000 1.00 12 12
0.769444 0.00 12 13
0.606667 0.04 12 14
0.688611 0.00 12 15
0.509444 0.86 12 16
0.789722 0.00 12 17
0.604722 0.05 12 18
0.934091 0.00 12 19
0.874583 0.00 12 20
0.614231 0.11 1 2
0.500000 1.00 13 13
0.664028 0.00 13 14
0.627500 0.02 13 15
0.803194 0.00 13 16
0.517500 0.74 13 17
0.515278 0.78 13 18
0.781439 0.00 13 19
0.634861 0.01 13 20
0.567667 0.34 1 3
0.500000 1.00 14 14
0.559583 0.26 14 15
0.616111 0.03 14 16
0.669306 0.00 14 17
0.569583 0.19 14 18
0.874242 0.00 14 19
0.772083 0.00 14 20
0.580000 0.25 1 4
0.500000 1.00 15 15
0.735139 0.00 15 16
0.656944 0.00 15 17
0.502083 0.97 15 18
0.890341 0.00 15 19
0.791944 0.00 15 20
0.787222 0.00 1 5
0.500000 1.00 16 16
0.821250 0.00 16 17
0.580278 0.13 16 18
0.950568 0.00 16 19
0.908750 0.00 16 20
0.510333 0.88 1 6
0.500000 1.00 17 17
0.502500 0.96 17 18
0.795644 0.00 17 19
0.625556 0.02 17 20
0.797333 0.00 1 7
0.500000 1.00 18 18
0.617235 0.04 18 19
0.516250 0.76 18 20
0.732000 0.00 1 8
0.500000 1.00 19 19
0.720265 0.00 19 20
0.851228 0.00 1 9
0.500000 1.00 20 20
0.797917 0.00 2 10
0.709455 0.00 2 11
0.675641 0.00 2 12
0.876282 0.00 2 13
0.741667 0.00 2 14
0.851442 0.00 2 15
0.710256 0.00 2 16
0.880128 0.00 2 17
0.694872 0.00 2 18
0.949519 0.00 2 19
0.912500 0.00 2 20
0.500000 1.00 2 2
0.867308 0.00 2 3
0.891667 0.00 2 4
0.763889 0.00 2 5
0.694872 0.00 2 6
0.785256 0.00 2 7
0.729647 0.00 2 8
0.844298 0.00 2 9
0.991250 0.00 3 10
0.943194 0.00 3 11
0.930972 0.00 3 12
0.999167 0.00 3 13
0.963472 0.00 3 14
0.999722 0.00 3 15
0.964167 0.00 3 16
0.998333 0.00 3 17
0.921944 0.00 3 18
1.000000 0.00 3 19
1.000000 0.00 3 20
0.500000 1.00 3 3
0.572222 0.18 3 4
0.975463 0.00 3 5
0.752639 0.00 3 6
0.985278 0.00 3 7
0.978889 0.00 3 8
0.991520 0.00 3 9
0.979444 0.00 4 10
0.948611 0.00 4 11
0.938056 0.00 4 12
0.992917 0.00 4 13
0.964583 0.00 4 14
0.991250 0.00 4 15
0.963472 0.00 4 16
0.994444 0.00 4 17
0.935139 0.00 4 18
1.000000 0.00 4 19
0.998333 0.00 4 20
0.500000 1.00 4 4
0.968056 0.00 4 5
0.806389 0.00 4 6
0.975278 0.00 4 7
0.965972 0.00 4 8
0.984942 0.00 4 9
0.522685 0.72 5 10
0.503241 0.96 5 11
0.576389 0.21 5 12
0.679861 0.00 5 13
0.509259 0.89 5 14
0.632176 0.03 5 15
0.594907 0.13 5 16
0.698148 0.00 5 17
0.502315 0.97 5 18
0.823232 0.00 5 19
0.767824 0.00 5 20
0.500000 1.00 5 5
0.921991 0.00 5 6
0.514815 0.80 5 7
0.615741 0.06 5 8
0.624513 0.04 5 9
0.954444 0.00 6 10
0.844583 0.00 6 11
0.834722 0.00 6 12
0.979306 0.00 6 13
0.889444 0.00 6 14
0.977222 0.00 6 15
0.895972 0.00 6 16
0.980000 0.00 6 17
0.813194 0.00 6 18
0.992045 0.00 6 19
0.984028 0.00 6 20
0.500000 1.00 6 6
0.940556 0.00 6 7
0.920139 0.00 6 8
0.960088 0.00 6 9
0.501389 0.98 7 10
0.529028 0.59 7 11
0.584028 0.11 7 12
0.723611 0.00 7 13
0.533750 0.52 7 14
0.648472 0.01 7 15
0.617222 0.03 7 16
0.755694 0.00 7 17
0.535139 0.52 7 18
0.929735 0.00 7 19
0.864861 0.00 7 20
0.500000 1.00 7 7
0.665278 0.00 7 8
0.656287 0.00 7 9
0.660694 0.00 8 10
0.586944 0.11 8 11
0.531667 0.55 8 12
0.838889 0.00 8 13
0.630000 0.01 8 14
0.803056 0.00 8 15
0.509028 0.87 8 16
0.861944 0.00 8 17
0.569722 0.19 8 18
0.969697 0.00 8 19
0.935833 0.00 8 20
0.500000 1.00 8 8
0.761696 0.00 8 9
0.652485 0.00 9 10
0.590936 0.09 9 11
0.718567 0.00 9 12
0.539766 0.46 9 13
0.629532 0.01 9 14
0.560819 0.27 9 15
0.747953 0.00 9 16
0.548099 0.37 9 17
0.519006 0.72 9 18
0.770734 0.00 9 19
0.646345 0.01 9 20
0.500000 1.00 9 9
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = 'areas-ns.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(data_file, delim_whitespace=True,header=0)
df = df.sort_values(by=['i','j','ns','areas'], ascending=[True,True,True,True])
areas = np.array(df)[:,0]
ns = np.array(df)[:,1]
grupo1 = np.array(df)[:,2]
grupo2 = np.array(df)[:,3]

def make_sym_matrix(n):
  m = np.zeros([n,n], dtype=np.double)
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        m[i,j]= ns[20*i+j] # here is the problem
        m[j,i]=m[i,j]
  return m

print ns
print make_sym_matrix(20)
```

Comment: I tested your code. Due to data is incomplete, except index out of bounds as expected, I did not see any problem. Would you elaborate further what questions you have in mind?

Comment: @White, I edited with all data. I don't know what should be the right definition `m[i,j]= ns[ ??? ]` to obtain the symmetric matrix. Since I sorted the `df` I suppose that first entry should correspond to `1 1` in the data, and so on.

Comment: You could use this to retrieve ns values for given i,j df[(df['i']==1)&(df['j']==10)]['ns'].values[0] if it's your goal.Not sure whether this is what you want to do. Usually with pandas, for loop is not used often if you could achieve it with column operations

Comment: @White, thanks. I believe that your code is OK. I tried some similar but I didn't use `values[0]`. I'll check if the loop is right.

Answer (score 8):

Probably is a better way but I think this works using an `unstack()` trick.   It would be helpful if you made your example data smaller btw.

By setting two columns as indexes, and then unstacking one of them, we essentially convert data into a square shape:

```
arr = df.set_index(['i','j'])['ns'].unstack().values

print(arr[:4,:4])

[[ 1.    0.11  0.34  0.25]
 [  nan  1.    0.    0.  ]
 [  nan   nan  1.    0.18]
 [  nan   nan   nan  1.  ]]
```

As you can see above, this is an upper triangle matrix, which we can pretty easily make into a symetric matrix using the handy numpy function `triu` along with a transpose (`T`):

```
arr2 = np.triu(arr) + np.triu(arr,1).T

print(arr2[:4,:4])

[[ 1.    0.11  0.34  0.25]
 [ 0.11  1.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.34  0.    1.    0.18]
 [ 0.25  0.    0.18  1.  ]]
```